# e-mail passwords from localhost wordpress are not being received

Tags: wordpress, macos, xampp

The users trying to register on my local-host WordPress are not receiving passwords. The WordPress is on XAMPP and the operating system is OS X Yosemite10.10.2

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure XAMPP to be able to send emails ?

See here : [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)